# jQuery autocomplete does not show all results

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display autocomplete for a form field but jQuery only displays 10 results as my data array has 42.
I do not understand why ?

Thanks !

I tried to log data values and the array contains 42 elements but formatItem function is only called 10 times.

```
    $(this).autocomplete('ajax_products_list.php?forceJson=0', {
        cacheLength:0,
        parse: function(data){
            parsed_data = [];
            tmp = data.split('\n');
            for (i=0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
                obj = tmp[i].split('|');
                parsed_data[i] = {
                    data: obj[0],
                    value: obj[1],
                };
            }

            return parsed_data
        },
        formatItem: function (item, position, length){
            return item;
        }
    }).result(addAssociation)
```

Comment: How many `\n` are there?

Comment: Does the split return a tmp with length of 42?

Comment: why all this splitting and formatting? Why not just make the server return JSON to start with? Much easier - you can do it in one line of PHP.

Comment: Hi, there are 42 \n php script return results like this : echo implode("\n", $data);

Comment: Yes the tmp length is 42, I don't understand why formatItem is only called 10 times

Comment: BTW which plugin are you using exactly? As far as I can see only [this one](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) has a "formatItem" callback...and it's been discontinued for almost 10 years now. Are you really still using that??

Comment: P.S. Is there any pattern to which 10 items the formatItem method is called for? Is it just the first 10? Or something else? That might give us a clue. And have you checked that the final `parsed_data` returned to the autocomplete actually contains the 42 items with all the data you expected?

Comment: Thanks for your help @ADyson, I'm using the last autocomplete jquery plugin I found and it seems to be up to date. Yes it's the first 10 items and everything seems to be good with the parsed_data I also tried to set manually an array of data and I have the same issue.

Comment: "I'm using the last autocomplete jquery plugin I found"... which one was the last one you found, then?? can you link us to it specifically? Is it the one I mentioned above? The most current one is http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ but that doesn't support your "formatItem" callback - it has other ways of achieving the same thing.

Comment: Anyway since the plugin I _think_ you're using is very old and has not been maintained for nearly 10 years, it's not impossible that your issue is something to do with an incompatibility between that code and modern browsers. Without reading the whole source code of the plugin and/or stepping through the code line by line (which I'm not going to do, but maybe you can if you like) it's really hard to say what the problem is. The code you've posted above doesn't, if your statements about the data values are correct - have any problems in it.

Comment: But TBH my advice overall would be to use a modern, mainstream, maintained plugin such as http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and also make your server output JSON so you don't have to do all this messing about with custom string formats.